# How to access a system without sending malicious program to victim sytem

Tags: information-gathering

Is their is any way to access a system without sending any malicious program...
Suppose I have my pc with an internet connection and with the victim ip so can I access the victim system if tcp ports are open ?

Comment: MAC addresses are largely *uninteresting*. IP's **may** be interesting if the host is listening to the network. Any remote attacks giving control is typically considered very serious, and patched quickly by software vendors.

Comment: SSH can be used to "access a system without sending any rat or malicious program", but this is probably not what you mean. You will need to be more specific

Comment: Sir I need to understand that how we can actually attack on the system with the system ip or maybe if we not have system ip so how we can get access in that system with sending any infected packet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of way to compromise a system without using a RAT or a backdoor. In fact, in order to drop a RAT or a backdoor on a system, you need to either compromise it first, or trick the user into installing that program in the first place.

RDP bruteforcing, SSH bruteforcing, service (network) exploitation are common ways of attacking a system to gain access to it. Depending on what system we're talking about, it might even be possible to do some recon (ex: file server with a loose security) to find information that could help you access it normally (ex: finding a file with a list of users/passwords, and using one of these to login to that system via RDP).

In order to "access" a system using only it's IP address, you need to do some recon and scan on it first, to find possible entry points and then either force your way through them, or exploit them.

Comment: Sir If the system is a  simple computer with internet connection ?

Comment: @lq not without open ports.no

Comment: "Internet connection" is still kind of vague. If that computer have vulnerable services exposed to the Internet (ie: telnet, ftp, etc.) then in that case, you could try to exploit them to gain access. If that computer only has access to the Internet for web browsing (ports 80 and 443 for instance), then you can try to SE the user behind it and direct him to a specifically crafted page that would exploit a flaw on his system and give you access (but that would involve dropping a malicious program on it, like a RAT or backdoor trojan).

Comment: If we bind all things so the answer is their is no other way to access simply to a victim computer without dropping any malicious program

Comment: Most of the things are easy to say that you can access with that or those but if the victim is aware of these all attacks and he fix all his system vulnerability then its possible to access ?